# Unexpected result when XOR-ing file in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

I want XOR the first 100 bytes of a file. Foreach 25 bytes will be xor-ed with the given `KEY` and repeated until it reach 100 bytes (circular xor). The problem is the output isn't what I expected.

For example, I tried to xor the these encrypted bytes:

```
2B 51 04 66 66 49 49 33 47 67 42 57 70 5A 60 08
DA 78 36 69 61 33 74 A8 82 0B 37 7D 34 10 24 3B
51 2E 14 42 57 70 5A 44 77 F8 7A 36 69 61 33 6B
46 DE 66 36 63 35 66 4B F1 32 08 00 25 04 70 5A
46 33 54 7A 36 69 61 33 4D 7D BE 66 37 63 35 66
12 D5 48 AE C2 BD A8 8F A5 B9 CC AB 85 C9 96 9E
CC 94 B9 CF
```

The expected result would be: (It's Ogg file)
*[See the live preview at CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27Space%27)Encode_text(%27UTF-8%20(65001)%27/disabled)XOR(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2764,36,63,35,66,4b,49,33,47,67,42,57,70,5a,46,33,54,7a,36,69,61,33,6b,46,30%27%7D,%27Standard%27,false)To_Hex(%27Space%27,0)&input=MkIgNTEgMDQgNjYgNjYgNDkgNDkgMzMgNDcgNjcgNDIgNTcgNzAgNUEgNjAgMDgNCkRBIDc4IDM2IDY5IDYxIDMzIDc0IEE4IDgyIDBCIDM3IDdEIDM0IDEwIDI0IDNCDQo1MSAyRSAxNCA0MiA1NyA3MCA1QSA0NCA3NyBGOCA3QSAzNiA2OSA2MSAzMyA2Qg0KNDYgREUgNjYgMzYgNjMgMzUgNjYgNEIgRjEgMzIgMDggMDAgMjUgMDQgNzAgNUENCjQ2IDMzIDU0IDdBIDM2IDY5IDYxIDMzIDREIDdEIEJFIDY2IDM3IDYzIDM1IDY2DQoxMiBENSA0OCBBRSBDMiBCRCBBOCA4RiBBNSBCOSBDQyBBQiA4NSBDOSA5NiA5RQ0KQ0MgOTQgQjkgQ0YNCg)*

```
4F 67 67 53 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 26 3B
8E 02 00 00 00 00 1F EE B2 6F 01 1E 01 76 6F 72
62 69 73 00 00 00 00 02 44 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 EE 02 00 00 00 00 00 B8 01 4F 67 67 53 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 26 3B 8E 02 01 00 00 00
59 9C 7B E9 A5 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF
```

But, the actual result I get is:

```
1B 17 6F 55 07 20 7F 49 13 54 04 0D 00 0D 22 6F
9D 4B 7F 22 07 06 17 9E E6 3B 71 16 07 71 4D 0D
2B 7A 27 04 0D 00 0D 06 10 BF 49 7F 22 07 06 08
70 BA 56 70 08 06 07 22 C7 48 5C 33 63 5E 00 0D
04 54 13 49 7F 22 07 06 2E 4B DA 56 71 08 06 07
7B E3 32 FA F1 FB F2 FF F2 FB AB EC B6 80 DD F8
F9 F7 8F AB
```

How did I know the actual result I want?
I use [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27Space%27)Encode_text(%27UTF-8%20(65001)%27/disabled)XOR(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2764,36,63,35,66,4b,49,33,47,67,42,57,70,5a,46,33,54,7a,36,69,61,33,6b,46,30%27%7D,%27Standard%27,false)To_Hex(%27Space%27,0)&input=MkIgNTEgMDQgNjYgNjYgNDkgNDkgMzMgNDcgNjcgNDIgNTcgNzAgNUEgNjAgMDgNCkRBIDc4IDM2IDY5IDYxIDMzIDc0IEE4IDgyIDBCIDM3IDdEIDM0IDEwIDI0IDNCDQo1MSAyRSAxNCA0MiA1NyA3MCA1QSA0NCA3NyBGOCA3QSAzNiA2OSA2MSAzMyA2Qg0KNDYgREUgNjYgMzYgNjMgMzUgNjYgNEIgRjEgMzIgMDggMDAgMjUgMDQgNzAgNUENCjQ2IDMzIDU0IDdBIDM2IDY5IDYxIDMzIDREIDdEIEJFIDY2IDM3IDYzIDM1IDY2DQoxMiBENSA0OCBBRSBDMiBCRCBBOCA4RiBBNSBCOSBDQyBBQiA4NSBDOSA5NiA5RQ0KQ0MgOTQgQjkgQ0YNCg) and it's give me what I want.

Here's my current code implementation. Did I miss something?

```cs
static readonly byte[] KEY = { 0x64,0x36,0x63,0x35,0x66,0x4b,0x49,0x33,0x47,0x67,0x42,0x57,0x70,0x5a,0x46,0x33,0x54,0x7a,0x36,0x69,0x61,0x33,0x6b,0x46,0x30 };

static void XORFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        int bufferLength;

        using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            buffer = new byte[bufferLength = (int)inputStream.Length];
            inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }

        if (bufferLength < 100)
        {
            if (bufferLength == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Skipping {filePath}. File is empty.");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
             // XOR the first 100 bytes
             for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
             {
                 buffer[i] ^= KEY[i % KEY.Length];
             }
        }

        using FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath);
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Sorry, I'm actually the dumb one. Actually, I didn't only xor the first 100 bytes, but also the last 100 bytes of a file. The code I provided above is actually work if I **only xor the first 100 bytes** and it's **output** the **expected result**.
When it came to xor-ing the last 100 bytes with the `REVERSED_KEY`, somehow the first 100 bytes didn't output the **expected result** again, but **actual result**. What's going on here? I'm really confused.

Updated code:

```cs
static readonly byte[] KEY = { 0x64,0x36,0x63,0x35,0x66,0x4b,0x49,0x33,0x47,0x67,0x42,0x57,0x70,0x5a,0x46,0x33,0x54,0x7a,0x36,0x69,0x61,0x33,0x6b,0x46,0x30 };

static void XORFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        int bufferLength;
        byte[] REVERSED_KEY = KEY;
        Array.Reverse(REVERSED_KEY);

        using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            buffer = new byte[bufferLength = (int)inputStream.Length];
            inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }

        if (bufferLength < 100)
        {
            if (bufferLength == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Skipping {filePath}. File is empty.");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // XOR the first 100 bytes
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                buffer[i] ^= KEY[i % KEY.Length];

            // XOR the last 100 bytes
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                buffer[bufferLength - 100 + i] ^= REVERSED_KEY[i % KEY.Length];

            using FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath);
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you accessing `KEY`'s index at `i % KEY.Length`? Your `KEY` should be the same size as the amount of data you're reading. Just use `i` to access your `KEY` array.

Comment: @SimonC It's circular xor(?). The loop iterates over the first 100 bytes (indices 0 to 99) of the `buffer` array.
For each byte at index `i` in the `buffer`, it performs the XOR operation with the corresponding byte at index `i % 25` in the `KEY` array. The `%` operator calculates the remainder of the division of `i by 25`, ensuring that the indices of the `KEY` array repeat cyclically every 25 bytes.

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? If it is anything security related, use real encryption methods. If it is for learning, write a unit test to verify that the output is as expected for some different data. For example a all-zero buffer.

Comment: @JonasH I'm just learning XOR cipher, not any high security encryption for real world application. Unit test? Not know about this :( I'll do some Googling about it. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you do "From HexDump" instead of "From Hex" in CyperChef?

Comment: Can you show the result of `Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer));` after you first reading the file?

Comment: An "OGG" file should always begin with the ASCII bytes for "OggS", so what you have there is clearly *not* an OGG file.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, his expected result does indeed start with "Oggs".

Comment: Oops I was looking at the encrypted bytes rather than the unencrypted ones...

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods > What happens if you do "From HexDump" instead of "From Hex" in CyperChef?
It didn't output anything.

Comment: Meh. Ok. I am still a little confused about your input data. From where do you get that _exactly_? It's a file, I get that. But what has been done to it? How has it been created?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is because you don't read `hex byte array` from the file. What you are reading is as follows:

> 0x32 0x42 0x20 ...

[image]

edit code as follow:

```
   /* using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        buffer = new byte[bufferLength = (int)inputStream.Length];
        inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    }*/
buffer = File.ReadAllText(filePath).Replace("\r\n"," ").Split(' ')
          .Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

[image]

Now the data in the `buffer` is as follows:

> 0x2b 0x51 0x04 0x66 ...

There is also a problem with `writing to the file` and it `doesn't even compile`. Edit your code as follows

```
 //using FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath);
//outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, String.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(buffer, x => x.ToString("X2")+' ')));
```

If you make this change, your code will be correct and the result will be as follows:

**result:**

> 4F 67 67 53 00 02 00 00 00 ...

**Note:**
I know I shouldn't use the image. But I put both text and image so that the QA can understand. hope this help you...

Comment: _"The expected result would be: (It's Ogg file)"_ - I would have expected an Ogg File to be binary, not text encoded bytes ... so something is _really_ off here if reading in text and _converting_ it to byte yields the _expected_ result. That leads me to the suspicion that the _expectation_ might have been wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it when I'm back home XD. If it's work, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @kiraio I tested and it was correct. You can also test

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods If you read the file as text, you will get exactly the same results as the questioner got. So it is a text file :)

Comment: _"That leads me to the suspicion that the expectation might have been wrong."_ - Which further leads me to the suggestion to separate input aquisition from building the cipher. Then you can test if your cipher method works and whether your data acquisition works.

Comment: _"So it is a text file"_ - That's what I am saying: _it should not be_. => [Ogg File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg#File_format)

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods In my opinion, it should not be, but it is...

Comment: There is another possibility: It's not. But the expected result is wrong. Two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: I can't get the same results. If the first byte is read as 0x32, `0x32 ^ 0x64 = 0x56`, how was the byte `1B` or the char `'1'` obtained?

Comment: I did what you suggest and it's throwing the following error: "An error occurred: Could not find any recognizable digits."